# Nginx error is not written to my error_log directive

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

On Ubuntu, when I try to restart my Nginx, I got some errors, but they are not written to my error_log directive, but still to the default /var/log/nginx/error.log
My nginx.conf looks something like this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    charset     utf-8

    error_log /home/ubuntu/nginxerror.log;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        }
    }
```

I actually have some ideas of this, if you pay attention, you should see I forgot ";" after "charset utf-8", and this is the reason why nginx fails on startup, I guess since the syntax is not correct, nginx config did not successfully load, and all the errors just go to the default log.

Does anyone know why.

Comment: So what the question then?

Comment: I just confirm my assumption is correct "since the syntax is not correct, nginx config did not successfully load, and all the errors just go to the default log.", is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to check if your nginx configuration is using following command:
`$ nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t`

Error in your sites configuration and in in nginx.conf file itself are logging according to `error_log` directive ([docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log)) in your configuration `http` section, `/var/log/nginx/error.log` by default.